# Looping over all combinations of items in Key Table

Tags: powershell

I'm looking to run web queries with different query strings based on pre-scraped data.

I am able to get the data into a Key Table format quite easily:

```
$ParamKeyTable = @{
    "Param1" = @(1, 8, 16)
    "Param2" = @(2, 5, 7 )
}
```

I would then like to loop over all combinations of members so that I can run 'all possible' queries against the web service.

an example would be using something like:

```
foreach ($Param1 in $ParamKeyTable['Param1']){
    foreach ($Param2 in $ParamKeyTable['Param2']){
        "Param1 = $('{0:00}' -f $Param1) ; Param2 = $('{0:00}' -f $Param2)"
        $UseInUrl = @{
            "Param1" = $Param1
            "Param2" = $Param2
        }
    }
}
```

however the number of parameters, as well as the names of them may change from time to time, I only need the `$UseInUrl` object at the end, so any format of getting permutations and turning them into the format of `$UseInUrl` will work for me.

I've tried using a `for` loop with the calculated final number of permutations, and then using modulo to determine which value to use from which key, but haven't been able to get this to work at all, i've also tried looping over the keys with separate counters, but haven't found a way to make this as scalable as i'd like.

the closest I've gotten is something like this, but I haven't been able to find a reasonable way of handling incrementing only the first counter key..

```
$ParamKeyTable = [ordered]@{
    "Param1" = @(1, 8, 16)
    "Param2" = @(2, 5, 7 )
}

$Counter = [ordered]@{}
foreach ($Key in $ParamKeyTable.Keys){
    $Counter[$Key] = 0
}

do {
    $UseInUrl = @(foreach ($Key in $ParamKeyTable.Keys){
        if ($Counter[$Key] -le $ParamKeyTable[$Key].Count){
            $Counter[$Key]++
        }

        #logic that actually makes this work goes here

        [PSCustomObject]@{
            $Key = $ParamKeyTable[$Key][$Counter[$Key]]
        }
    })
} while ($UseInUrl -ne $null)
```

any help or advice would be much appreciated.

Comment: Iterating and overwriting a single variable each time doesn't make sense to me. What output do you expect?

Comment: @LotPings i'm looking to get objects of some form, which can tell me `Param1 = 01 : Param2 = 02` or `Param1 = 01 : Param2 = 05` etc. and be able to operate on each one of them, something like the `$UseInUrl` object.

Answer (score 0):

Still a bit unclear what you are after, this script:

```
## Q:\Test\2018\09\28\SO_52557811.ps1

$ParamKeyTable = @{
     "Param1" = @(1, 8, 16)
     "Param2" = @(2, 5, 7 )
 }

$UseInUrl = foreach ($Param1 in $ParamKeyTable['Param1']){
    foreach ($Param2 in $ParamKeyTable['Param2']){
         [PSCustomObject]@{
            "Param1" = $Param1
            "Param2" = $Param2
        }
    }
}
$UseInUrl
```

Will have this output with all all iterations:

```
> Q:\Test\2018\09\28\SO_52557811.ps1

Param1 Param2
------ ------
     1      2
     1      5
     1      7
     8      2
     8      5
     8      7
    16      2
    16      5
    16      7
```

Comment: My issue is that I could add a "param3", or that they could be named "Foo" and "Bar" instead, I'm looking to avoid hardcoding the names entirely

Comment: Without prior knowledge of the hashtable keys you can enumerate them like this `$ParamKeyTable.GetEnumerator()|ForEach-Object{"{0}={1}" -f $_.name,($_.Value -join ',')}`

Comment: I'm looking to iterate over them as in the question, all combinations of all values, not just key value pairs.